# Select a wpf datagrid row programmaticaly with the highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I created a datagrid in WPF with a few rows.
I created four buttons on my wpf grid in order to navigate between the rows :  [<<] -- [<] -- [>] --  [>>]

I use the SelectedItem function in order to set the rows.
My problem is that the highlighting appear to be bad ( slow ) to appear ( it's a bit difficult to explain ).

When i use the keybord arrow (up and down) in order to  between the rows, the highlighting is fast and immediate. Whit my code behind my button, the highlighting is a bit slow and strange.

**Here is my code**

```
        private void Button_Click_Goto_Premier(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items[0];
        myDataGridEvtCode.Focus();
    }

    private void Button_Click_Goto_Precedent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items[myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedIndex - 1];
            myDataGridEvtCode.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_Goto_Suivant(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedIndex < myDataGridEvtCode.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items[myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedIndex + 1];
            myDataGridEvtCode.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_Goto_Dernier(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items[myDataGridEvtCode.Items.Count-1];
        myDataGridEvtCode.Focus();
    }
```

Anyone have some ideas about this ?

Thanks a lot my friends :)

Comment: I can't tell you why this is slow. Maybe your collection of items is very big and the data grid lacks of virtualization.
Have you heard of LINQ? It might make your code a bit easier. For selecting the first item you'd write `myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items.FirstOrDefault()`, for the last `myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedItem = myDataGridEvtCode.Items.LastOrDefault()`. It doesn't throw exceptions in case the collection is empty, as your current code would. It would just return `null`, if it's empty. There's `.First()` and `.Last()` available, either. These throw exceptions.

Comment: I juste have four row  with 2 columns ! My collection is little ! I think its a code problem

Comment: Do you use the standard `DataGrid`? Or some thrid-party grid?

Comment: Yes, standard datagrid !

Comment: So watch my answer, I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume, you use `System.Windows.Control.DataGrid`. I didn't try your code. Here's some code, I just threw together in a samlple WPF app. Selection through pressing the buttons works as fluently as selecting rows manually with my mouse/keyboard.

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" Height="200"/>
        <Button Content="Previous" Click="Previous"/>
        <Button Content="Next" Click="Next"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Code behind

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var persons = new List<Person>
                {
                    new Person("Steve", "Jobs"),
                    new Person("Bill", "Gates"),
                    new Person("Dan", "Brown"),
                    new Person("Barack", "Obama")
                };

            MyGrid.ItemsSource = persons;
        }

        private void Next(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyGrid.Focus();

            int nextIndex = MyGrid.SelectedIndex + 1;
            if (nextIndex > MyGrid.Items.Count - 1) return;
            MyGrid.SelectedIndex = nextIndex;
        }

        private void Previous(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyGrid.Focus();

            int previousIndex = MyGrid.SelectedIndex - 1;
            if (previousIndex < 0) return;
            MyGrid.SelectedIndex = previousIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Working with indicies might be the clue. Though I haven't searched for a proof, yet.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your sample code, it appear to be good ! I will try to modify my code in a few hour :) Thanks !