# WPF DataGrid loses focus on down Arrow

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus

Just hoping someone could please help me out here?

I've got a DataGrid (SelectionUnit="FullRow").

If I give the dg focus by mouse click, then use up/down arrow, it works as expect (ie a new row is selected each time press up or down).

If I give the dg focus using codebehind, and select the first row, it looks like it works. The first row is selected. If I then press down arrow, focus is lost and no rows are selected.

Here the code I'm using to give the dg focus;

```
dg_results.Focus();
object item = dg_results.Items[0];
dg_results.SelectedItem = item;
dg_results.ScrollIntoView(item);
```

thanks all

Comment: I found an answer here; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63ceae0a-8231-4708-8835-bbc615d4e049/datagrid-focus-from-code

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Keyboard.Focus` too, there are two type of focuses in WPF

```
Keyboard.Focus(dg_results);
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx#Keyboard_Focus) for more details

Comment: Thanks, but similar problem. I've overridden the dg.Resources and set HighlightBrushKey to Red, and ControlBrushKey to Green. When I give the dg keyboard focus and select the first row, the first row is Red. Down Arrow once changes the colour of the first row to Green. Down arrow again does nothing (colour remains Green, and additional down arrows seem to do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw a question like this here, but unfortunately, I can't remember which one it was. After performing a quick search however, I found a post with a correct answer. Please take a look at this [Select a wpf datagrid row programmaticaly with the highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121723/select-a-wpf-datagrid-row-programmaticaly-with-the-highlighting) post for an answer.

Comment: Cheers, I'd tried that, and it only half works, sadly. It displays the same behaviour that I described above. The focus isn't quite right. If I press button[item 0], button[1], and button[2], then Item[2] will be Red. Pressing down arrow now (as opposed to button) will result in NOT a row change, but rather Item[2] will lose focus of some kind, changing from Red to Green. There's a difference in the focus the DG has between clicking on it with a mouse and setting dg.Focus();